# pass query param as dictionary with many values in postman

Tags: django, python-3.x, postman

I am using `postman` to hit my APIs. I have a question regarding sending query params through postman `params`. In my API i am getting params using `services = request.GET.get('services')` and then returning response for the services.

My Question is if have more than one service like 'A', 'B', 'C', then how can we send these services in params using postman?

**views.py**

```
class SomeAPIView(ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        services = self.request.GET.get('services')
        print(services)            # getting  services
        print(type(services))      #type is string
        response_list = []
        for service in services:
            result = API(service=service)
            response_list.append(result)
        return response_list
```

I want get list of services and then iterate over that list to return response for that service.

Comment: can you please add ur code what have you done

Comment: hi, i have added sample of my code.

Answer (score 0):

It depending on how you would use this API entry in production.

At first, the good way in django is to use `request.query_params` to obtain query parameters. Also you must provide default value to `get()` method to avoid exceptions if there's no 'services' parameter passed.

Then, if your services parameter contain names or ids of some objects, you may just pass it with parameters in GET request as http://someurl?services=A,B,C, or within tab, named 'Params' in postman. So `request.query_params.get('sevices', '')` will return string, contains 'A,B,C'. Now you can split it by ',' like `services_names = str.split(',')`.

Anyway, parameters of GET requests may return only `str` values.

According to your example, it may looks like:

```py
class SomeAPIView(ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        services = self.request.query_params.get('sevices', '').split(',')
        print(services)            # getting  services
        print(type(services))      # now it will be List[str]
        response_list = []
        for service in services:
            result = API(service=service)
            response_list.append(result)
        return response_list
```